# Gettting contact list in android it taking time and crashing app

Tags: android, android-contacts

In my android app  i am trying to getting contacts list from my phonebook there is 1000 contacts app is taking to much time to load contacts and also it crashes here is my code
when contacts is loading it not responding app is crashes

```
private ArrayList<AllInOnetItem> getContacts() {
    String phoneNo = "";
    ArrayList<AllInOnetItem> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    //ContentResolver cResolver=context.getContextResolver();
    ContentProviderClient mCProviderClient = cr.acquireContentProviderClient(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        cur = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if ((cur != null ? cur.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
        while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Name: " + name);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNo);
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
            contacts.add(new AllInOnetItem(name, phoneNo));
        }
        sortlist(contacts);

        if (contactAdapter != null) {
            contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: please fetch contact in `background thread` . about crash please post your crash log

Comment: its just says app is not responding

Comment: at the time of crash . check your android studio logcat

Comment: contacts loaded but it takes to much time

Comment: perform contact fetching operation in `AsyncTask`

Comment: for what you need two nested `while` loops??

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```
        List<ContactVO> contactVOList = new ArrayList();


        private void getContacts() {

                AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                runner.execute();

            }


        private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            private String resp;
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                ContactVO contactVO;

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            contactVO = new ContactVO();
                            contactVO.setContactName(name);

                            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{id},
                                    null);
                            if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                contactVO.setContactNumber(phoneNumber);
                            }

                            phoneCursor.close();

                            Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{id}, null);
                            while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                            }
                            contactVOList.add(contactVO);
                        }
                    }



                }

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
                hideProgressBar();
                setContactAdapter();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              showProgressBar();
            }


        }



    public class ContactVO {
        private String ContactImage;
        private String ContactName;
        private String ContactNumber;
        private boolean isChecked;

        public String getContactImage() {
            return ContactImage;
        }

        public void setContactImage(String contactImage) {
            this.ContactImage = ContactImage;
        }

        public String getContactName() {
            return ContactName;
        }

        public void setContactName(String contactName) {
            ContactName = contactName;
        }

        public String getContactNumber() {
            return ContactNumber;
        }

        public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
            ContactNumber = contactNumber;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return isChecked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            isChecked = checked;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ContactNumber.replace(" ","");
        }
    }



public class AllContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllContactsAdapter.ContactViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<ContactVO> contactVOList,contactListFiltered;
    private Context mContext;

    public AllContactsAdapter(List<ContactVO> contactVOList, Context mContext){
        this.contactVOList = contactVOList;
        this.contactListFiltered = contactVOList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_contact_view, null);
        ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
        return contactViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ContactVO contactVO = contactListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.tvContactName.setText(contactVO.getContactName());
        holder.tvPhoneNumber.setText(contactVO.getContactNumber());

        holder.cbContact.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                 contactVO.setChecked(b);
            }
        });

        if(contactVO.isChecked()){
            holder.cbContact.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            holder.cbContact.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactListFiltered.size();
    }

    public List<ContactVO> getContacts(){
        return contactVOList;
    }

    public List<ContactVO> getSelectedContacts(){

        List<ContactVO> selectedContactVOList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < contactVOList.size(); i++) {
            if(contactVOList.get(i).isChecked()){
                selectedContactVOList.add(contactVOList.get(i));
            }
        }
        return selectedContactVOList;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    contactListFiltered = contactVOList;
                } else {
                    List<ContactVO> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ContactVO row : contactVOList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getContactName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getContactNumber().contains(charSequence)) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<ContactVO>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView ivContactImage;
        TextView tvContactName;
        TextView tvPhoneNumber;
        CheckBox cbContact;

        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ivContactImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            tvContactName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
            tvPhoneNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNumber);
            cbContact =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbContact);

        }
    }

}


 private void setContactAdapter() {
        contactAdapter = new AllContactsAdapter(contactVOList, getApplicationContext());
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SendSMSActivity.this));
        rvContacts.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        rlContacts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch your contacts in background thread. For background task you can use WorkManager, Firebase JobDispatcher, AsyncTask etc. If you will use AsyncTask then you have to keep in mind of memory leaking problem with context.